# Geography quiz python

Tags: python-2.7

I have an issue with my code. I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying new things. I want to create a geography quiz that will randomly ("but not repeatedly") select country that I have to guess its capital. Currently for every answer I get a message that my answer is wrong. The question is how exactly should I do things so that when I loop through the dictionary for a country, I will have to guess the correct key of that country.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2
import random


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=False)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        return self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        return self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

    def render_template(self, view_filename, params=None):
        if not params:
            params = {}
        template = jinja_env.get_template(view_filename)
        return self.response.out.write(template.render(params))

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        return self.render_template("geokviz.html")
class AboutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        return self.render_template("geokviz1.html")

class flagHandler(BaseHandler):
        def get(self):
            return self.render_template("flag.html")
class attractionHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        return self.render_template("attraction.html")

class Capital:
    def __init__(self, capital, country):
        self.capital = capital
        self.country = country

city = {"Zagreb":"Croatia", "Ljubljana":"Slovenia", "Rome":"Italy", "Oslo":"Norway"}


class capitalCityHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        for cities in random.sample(list(city), 1):
            capital = city[cities]

            params={"capital": capital}
            return self.render_template("capital.html", params=params)
    def post(self):
            odgovor = self.request.get("answer")
            if odgovor == city.keys():
                result1 = "You are right"
            else:
                result1 = "You are wrong"
            self.write(result1)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', MainHandler),
    webapp2.Route('/geo', AboutHandler),
    webapp2.Route('/city', capitalCityHandler),
    webapp2.Route('/flag', flagHandler),
    webapp2.Route('/attraction', attractionHandler),


], debug=True)
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if the capital exists as a key, then you may check if it matches the country.

```
if odgovor in city.keys() and city[odgovor] == country:
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not totally correct. What I want is that for every value only the the correct key will give me the answer "you are right". Right now any value that is in the dictionary will give me answer "you are right"